# Javascript: How do I dynamically create and merge text nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, nodes

This is a validate function that takes email input in and stores incorrect characters inside the bad array using match. What I want to do is be able to draw a line through incorrect characters using the S tag. If an email has one invalid character, such as ab+c@abc.abc, the line draws through the "+' correctly and displays ab<s>+</s>c@abc.abc However, if there is more than one invalid character, such as a+b+c@abc.abc, both '+' will be crossed out, but when it is displayed on the screen they will have moved next to each other, such as ab<s>++</s>c@abc.abc. I need help on how to get this text to display as a<s>+</s>b<s>+</s>c@abc.abc.

```
function validate()
{
  var str = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var len = str.length;

  var patt1 =  /^[^;,\':\?\!\*#\^&@\+\-]+\w+@{1}\w+\.{1}\w+$/;
```

If we pass the regex test, the email is valid.

```
  if(patt1.test(str))
  {
    document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "valid";
  }
```

Else, we will store the bad

```
  else
  {
    alert("not a valid email");
    document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "";
    var bad = str.match(/[;,\':\?\!\*#\^&@\+\-]+/);    

    var wholestr = document.getElementById("validate");

    var x = document.createElement("S");
```

Here, I tried to dynamically create variables in an array, all with their separate text nodes. This is first done for invalid characters, then valid characters. Each new text node is being appended to wholestr, which will display on the screen. The idea was for each character to be its own text node, so that the invalid chars would not be displayed side-by-side; however, it still occurs.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
      for(var j = 0; j < bad.length; j++)
      {
        if(str[i] == bad[j])
        {
           var errors = [];

           for(var k = 0; k < bad.length; k++)
           {
              errors[k] = document.createTextNode(bad[j]);
           }

           for(var k = 0; k < errors.length; k++)
           {
             x.appendChild(errors[k]);
             wholestr.appendChild(x);
           }

        }
        else
        {
           var valids = [];

           for(var k = 0; k < str.length; k++)
           {
              valids[k] = document.createTextNode(str[i]);
           }


            wholestr.appendChild(valids[i]);

           //var str1 = document.createTextNode("");
           //str1.textContent = str[i];
           //wholestr.appendChild(str1);
        }
      }  
    }

  }


}
```

Comment: this is an edit to the first paragraph, when ab+c@abc.abc is entered, the result is ab<s>+</s>c@abc.abc

Answer (score 0):

Just answered the question, my mistake was pretty basic, it had to do with the x element that contained the S tag.

```
function validate()
{
  var str = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var len = str.length;

  var patt1 =  /^[^;,\':\?\!\*#\^&@\+\-]+\w+@{1}\w+\.{1}\w+$/;

  if(patt1.test(str))
  {
    document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "valid";
  }
  else
  {
    alert("not a valid email");
    document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "";
    var bad = str.match(/[;,\':\?\!\*#\^&@\+\-]+/);    

    var wholestr = document.getElementById("validate");

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
      for(var j = 0; j < bad.length; j++)
      {
        if(str[i] == bad[j])
        {
           var errors = [];
```

Here what i needed was another dynamic array that stored elements with the S tag. So each invalid character node would be appended to its own document.createElement("S")

```
           var x = [];

           for(var k = 0; k < bad.length; k++)
           {  
              x[k] = document.createElement("S");
              errors[k] = document.createTextNode(bad[j]);
           }

           for(var k = 0; k < errors.length; k++)
           {
             x[k].appendChild(errors[k]);
             wholestr.appendChild(x[k]);
           }

        }
        else
        {
           var valids = [];

           for(var k = 0; k < str.length; k++)
           {
              valids[k] = document.createTextNode(str[i]);
           }


            wholestr.appendChild(valids[i]);

           //var str1 = document.createTextNode("");
           //str1.textContent = str[i];
           //wholestr.appendChild(str1);
        }
      }  
    }

  }


}
```